# Is there an optimum way to collect information/variables from a customer agreement document

Tags: python, nlp

Used the site for pretty much all of my academic and professional careers but first time posting.

I'm kicking around some at-home projects and I'm looking at how to use python to scrape variable information out of a customer engagement / agreement document to start then using within automatic document production.  The idea being to remove the admin job of someone reviewing and retyping the data received in from a new customer.

For example, the text we could be receiving in could be:

> Customer Agreement
>
> Customer Name: John Smith 
>   Date of agreement: 03/05/2020
>
> Pricing (per hour): Product Manager    £150 Developer  £170
>   Data Analyst  £200 Account Manager    £80
>
> Throughout the duration of our working relationship your main point of
>   contact will be Sally Horne.  We will contact you via your email
>   address: j.smith@fake-email.com and through writing we will use your
>   address as listed: 123 Home Le Street Townington County AB1 9HH
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin id consequat
>   lectus. Praesent justo lectus, ultricies vel nunc eu, sollicitudin
>   ullamcorper metus. Vivamus ac aliquet elit. In ullamcorper
>   sollicitudin ante et viverra. Suspendisse viverra a nisi ut dignissim.
>   Pellentesque ac pellentesque enim. Nunc dignissim felis at erat semper
>   luctus. Donec nec tristique lorem. Etiam iaculis accumsan massa, non
>   tempus turpis pharetra ac. Mauris turpis turpis, finibus nec mi non,
>   finibus pharetra diam.

I'm comfortable with getting the text out of the document using mammoth i.e.

```
import mammoth
global raw_text

with open("test.docx", "rb") as docx_file:
    result = mammoth.extract_raw_text(docx_file)
    raw_text = result.value
```

It's then the best way to approach achieving the goal: sifting out things like the pricing for each role, customer names, addresses used etc.

I've done a lot of digging and have found umpteen different approaches I could pursue!  Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: If the format is identical, one could use regular expression to extract information. However, if the format changes, then a custom entity extracting model can be trained as described [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/08/nlp-guide-conditional-random-fields-text-classification/)

Comment: Thanks SidharthMacherla that’s great!  Looks like it might do the trick!